# VLC auto adjust window size to video size

Tags: windows-8.1, vlc-media-player

when in windowed mode, the VLC window can be resized arbitrarily. It will however add black bars to the sides of the video, if the aspect ratio of the window does not match the aspect ratio of the video.

Is there a way to force the VLC WINDOW to match the aspect ratio of the video (NOT the other way round).

This is on Win8.1

Comment: What operating system are you using this on?

Comment: Menu > Video -> Alway Fit Window or Menu > Tools > Preferences > Resize interface to video size.

Comment: @DavidPostill neither option works... Always Fit Window has been renamed autoscale video I think and only fixes the video size to its original size, the window can still be resized arbitrarily. Resize Interface to Video Size doesn't seem to change anything at all.

Comment: @AMR this is Win8.1

Comment: @Xaser Hmm. It works here - If I first open VLS then drag & drop video the window resizes the match the video as expected.

Comment: @DavidPostill Xaser is the OP.

Comment: @AMR sorry, comment updated :/

Comment: @DavidPostill ok maybe it works when opening a new video, but I want to be able to resize it with the correct aspect ratio as well. So say the video is 500x500, i want to be able to resize the window only to f*500xf*500

Comment: I've got the same question. Is there really no way to do this? I can't even find anything here: https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line/#Video_options